# Convex set also has convex interior (Corollary)

Tags: proof-explanation, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

While studying convex analysis, i came across two statements:

**First statement:**

Let $S$ be a convex set in $R^{n}$ with a nonempty interior. Let $x_{1} \in \operatorname{cl} S$ and $x_{2} \in$ int
S. Then $\lambda x_{1}+(1-\lambda) x_{2} \in$ int $S$ for each $\lambda \in(0,1)$. **I understood the proof regarding this one.**

**Corollary:**

Let $S$ be a convex set. Then int $S$ is convex.

**My attempt:**

For int $S$ to be convex, one has to let $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$ $\in$ int $S$ and show that $\lambda x_{1}+(1-\lambda) x_{2} \in int(S)$. I see that is almost what the first statement says. **However**, in statement number one, $x_{1}$ belongs to the closure of the set $S$ and i need it in $int (S)$ to conclude.

In an attempt to solve this issue, i was trying to use set inclusions such as $S \subset$ $cl(S)$ or $cl(S) = S \cup \partial S$ to conclude that $x_{1} \in cl(S)$ $\implies$ $x_{1} \in int (S)$ with the help of the first statement.

However, i just can't figure out this corollary.

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance, Lucas

Comment: For every set $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, $\operatorname{Int}(S)\subset S\subset \operatorname{Cl}(S)$. If you already know that $S\subset\operatorname{Cl}(S)$. Then it suffices to prove that $\operatorname{Int}(S)\subset S$, which is a direct consecuence of the Interior definition. If $s\in\operatorname{Int}(S)$, then there exists $\delta\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $B(s,\delta)\subset S$, which implies that $s\in S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot conclude $x_{1} \in \text{cl}(S)$ $\implies$ $x_{1} \in \text{int} (S)$ because it is wrong. Just observe that the statement

> Let $x_{1} \in \operatorname{cl} S$ and $x_{2} \in$ int
> S. Then $\lambda x_{1}+(1-\lambda) x_{2} \in \text{int} (S)$ for each $\lambda \in(0,1)$

is **more general** than

> Let $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$ $\in$ int $S$. Then  $\lambda x_{1}+(1-\lambda) x_{2} \in \text{int} (S)$ for each $\lambda \in(0,1)$.

In fact, if $x_{1}, x_{2} \in$ int $S$, then $x_1 \in \text{int} (S) \subset S \subset \text{cl}(S)$ and $x_2 \in  \text{int} (S)$.